# Users system custom post type

Tags: profiles

Please tell me how to implement such a task.I have created a volunteer website for animals. To publish an animal, I use the custom post type - "pets".
Custom fields for content (custom field suite). Everything is working well. But in order for users to post animals on the site, I use the wpforms feedback form and then manually add animals to the site myself. But I would like to create a user system.:
User registration,
User creation of a custom type of posts (pets)
View your posts in your profile
Editing posts in a user's profile
I can create a custom post type and fill in fields via php using the custom field suite api. But I can't figure out how to connect this with users.
Site: dogcat.ge/pets